# Работа с фиксированными элементами на странице

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
Существует два блока, первый блок находится выше - это header. Блок, который расположен ниже это навигация. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы эти два блока были оба фиксированные и один не закрывал другой. При скроллинге, в определенном месте на странице указанном в px (к примеру), блок header резко скрывался, можно с затуханием, можно и без, предпочтительно резко, так как с затуханием, я уже более менее понимаю, но не полноценно конечно. Далее при возвращении обратно, header появлялся на том же уровне, что и исчезал. Приведу пример, на transparency.org реализован подобный случай. Вот image. [![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1] [![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]Там ещё реализованно изменение размера блока на меню навигации, но это уже не так важно. Также ещё понимаю, что кое-что можно с помощью плагинов сделать, просто это уже готовые варианты, хочется ещё реализацию понять. 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvgyP.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfAtb.png


Код реализующий затухание header с прилипанием навигации (menu). 
<script>
var tempScrollTop = 0, 
    currentScrollTop = 0;

$(window).on('scroll', 
    function() {        
        currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();        
        if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop )        
            $('#header_fade_out').fadeOut();        

        else 
            if (tempScrollTop > currentScrollTop )            
                $('#header_fade_out').fadeIn();                                   
            tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop;  
    })

</script>
<script>

 $(window).bind('scroll',function(){// 
  var ScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop(), // 
      HeaderHeight = $('.header').height() + 15; // 

  if(ScrollPos>HeaderHeight) { 
    $('.menu').addClass('fixed'); 

    $('.content').css('margin-top','50px'); 
  } else { // Если меньше, то
    $('.menu').removeClass('fixed'); 
    $('.content').css('margin-top','0'); 
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 230) {
                $(".sidedivs").addClass("fixess");
            } else {
                $('.sidedivs').removeClass("fixess");
            }
        });
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 115) {
                //$("header").hide(300);
                $("li.navicon").show(); 
                $(".navbar.menu").addClass("fixedsss");
            } else {
                $("li.navicon").hide();
                $('header').show("300");
                $(".navbar.menu").removeClass("fixedsss");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Собственно вот пример js, тут должно быть все понятно. При скроллинге появляются классы, а css уже прописать не проблема

Comment: в комментариях там ошибка или, для чего-то нужно

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, сейчас попробую прикрутить, только вот не могу понять, расположение кода вроде должно быть другое, 1 и 2 функция вроде должны поменяться местами. Хотя сейчас проверим. Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: так и не получилось у меня, всё здорово, блок исчезает там где нужно, только вот фиксация двух блоков не происходит, фиксируется только один

Comment: так что придётся ещё возиться, может ещё поспрашиваю, часа 4 потратил - скрипт не работает